# Swift 2.0 String behavior

Tags: swift2

> Strings in 2.0 no longer conform to **CollectionType**. Each character in the String is now an **Extended Graphene Cluster**.

Without digging too deep about the **Cluster** stuff, I tried a few things with Swift Strings:

[image]

String now has a `characters` property that contains what we humans recognize as *characters*. Each distinct character in the string is considered a character, and the `count` property gives us the number of distinct characters.

What I don't quite understand is, even though the `characters` count shows `10`, why does the `index` show emojis occupying 2 indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` of a `String` is no more related to the number of characters (`count`) in Swift 2.0. It is an “opaque” `struct` (defined as `CharacterView.Index`) used only to iterate through the characters of a string. So even if it is printed as an integer, it should *not* be considered or used as an integer, to which, for instance, you can sum 2 to get the second character from the current one. What you can do is only to apply the two methods `predecessor` and `successor` to get the previous or successive index in the `String`. So, for instance, to get the second character from that with index `idx` in `mixedString` you can do:

```
mixedString[idx.successor().successor()]
```

Of course you can use more confortable ways of reading the characters of string, like for instance, the `for` statement or the global function `indices(_:)`.

Consider that the main benefit of this approach is not to the threat multi-bytes characters in Unicode strings, as emoticons, but rather to treat in a uniform way *identical* (for us humans!) strings that can have multiple representations in Unicode, as different set of “scalars”, or characters. An example is `café`, that can be represented either with four Unicode “scalars” (unicode characters), or with five Unicode scalars. And note that this is a completely different thing from Unicode representations like UTF-8, UTF-16, etc., that are ways of mapping Unicode scalars into memory bytes.

Answer (score 0):

An Extended Graphene Cluster can still occupy multiple bytes, however, the correct way to determine the index position of a character would be:

```
let mixed = ("MADE IN THE USA ");
var index = mixed.rangeOfString("")
var intIndex: Int = distance(mixed.startIndex, index!.startIndex)
```

**Result**:

```
16
```

The way you are trying to get the index would normally be meant for an array, and I think Swift cannot properly work that out with your `mixedString`.