# how to convert element type to string in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I wanna get a key:value from a dict like this

```
var tmpDict = ["a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"]
var tmpString = "a1234"
print(tmpDict[tmpString.characters.first])
```

Here comes an error, something like tmpString.characters.first cannot convert to string, What can I do if I wanna call tmpDict[xxx], which "xxx" means the first character of tmpString.

Comment: Why not `var tmpDict: [Character : String]` ?

Comment: Cause the keys are not all Characters

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var tmpDict = ["a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"]
var tmpString = "a1234"
tmpDict[String(tmpString[tmpString.characters.startIndex])]
```

with `tmpString.characters.startIndex` you get the index of the first character of `tmpString`, then you use it to extract the first character, and finally convert this character to a String to access the dictionary.

Comment: That seems to work,but is it a normal use?what if second index?Cause characters only got startIndex and endIndex attribute

Comment: You have several possibilities. For instance you can use `...characters.indices` to get all the indices and iterate over them with a `for loop`. Or, having an index `i`, you can get the next index by using `i.successor()`, etc.. The reason of this approach is explained in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32168972/2382734).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is you can convert `tmpString` to `Array` and access it's first element this way:

```
tmpDict[String(Array(tmpString)[0])]  // "1"
```

Or you can use this extension:

```
extension String
{
    subscript(integerIndex: Int) -> Character
        {
            let index = advance(startIndex, integerIndex)
            return self[index]
    }

    subscript(integerRange: Range<Int>) -> String
        {
            let start = advance(startIndex, integerRange.startIndex)
            let end = advance(startIndex, integerRange.endIndex)
            let range = start..<end
            return self[range]
    }
}

var tmpDict = ["a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"]
var tmpString = "a1234"
print(tmpDict[String(tmpString[0])]!)  // "1"
```

For **2.0**

```
extension String
{
    subscript(integerIndex: Int) -> Character {
        let index = startIndex.advancedBy(integerIndex)
        return self[index]
    }

    subscript(integerRange: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = startIndex.advancedBy(integerRange.startIndex)
        let end = startIndex.advancedBy(integerRange.endIndex)
        let range = start..<end
        return self[range]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not working, I've tried in xcode7 beta6, it still got an error

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean the extension. tmpDict[String(Array(tmpString)[0])] is not working